# How does the EntityFunctions.DiffHours method work?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, datetime, timespan

I can't find anything in the docs that explain the details of this method. Because it always returns an integer, it doesn't distinguish between a time difference of 3:20 and a time difference of 3:10. But does it round up, or round down, or does it just compare the hours portion of 2 times?

Example: 
OpenTime = 2014-06-12 13:35:00.000
CloseTime = 2014-06-13 14:30:00.000

The actual difference is 24 hours and 55 minutes. Will this return a difference of 24 hours, or 25 hours?

I need to determine if 2 times are 25 hours or more apart; can I use DiffHours for this, or do I need to use DiffSeconds and divide the result by 3600 to get the actual hours?

Comment: `Will this return a difference of 24 hours, or 25 hours?` What happens when you try this yourself?

Comment: 25. But I don't know if that's because it's rounding up from 24.92, or if it's comparing the "13" in the open to the "14" in the close, and ignoring minutes completely.

Comment: Either way it's unexpected behavior; the difference between those 2 times is less than 25 hours.

Comment: It's going to ultimately translate to a SQL statement that performs the work, so if you trace with SQL Profiler you can see what it exactly does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One nice thing about EF is that it is all open-source.  If you dig through [this part of the source code](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlGen/SqlFunctionCallHandler.cs), you'll find:

```
functionHandlers.Add("DiffHours", HandleCanonicalFunctionDateDiff);
```

Which calls into:

```
// <summary>
// Handler for all date/time addition canonical functions.
// Translation, e.g.
// DiffYears(datetime, number) =>  DATEDIFF(year, number, datetime)
// </summary>
private static ISqlFragment HandleCanonicalFunctionDateDiff(SqlGenerator sqlgen, DbFunctionExpression e)
{
    var result = new SqlBuilder();

    result.Append("DATEDIFF (");
    result.Append(_dateDiffFunctionNameToDatepartDictionary[e.Function.Name]);
    result.Append(", ");
    result.Append(e.Arguments[0].Accept(sqlgen));
    result.Append(", ");
    result.Append(e.Arguments[1].Accept(sqlgen));
    result.Append(")");

    return result;
}
```

So there's your answer - calling `EntityFunctions.DiffHours` just translates to a call to the [native `DATEDIFF` function in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

Since `DATEDIFF` works by counting datepart boundaries, then it is simply truncating all seconds and comparing the year, month, day and hours components only.

Proof:

```sql
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour,'2014-01-01 00:00:00','2014-01-01 01:00:00')
-- returns 1 hour

SELECT DATEDIFF(hour,'2014-01-01 00:00:00','2014-01-01 01:01:00')
-- returns 1 hour

SELECT DATEDIFF(hour,'2014-01-01 00:00:00','2014-01-01 01:59:00')
-- returns 1 hour

SELECT DATEDIFF(hour,'2014-01-01 00:00:00','2014-01-01 00:59:00')
-- returns 0 hours
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll have to call DiffSeconds and divide by 3600 then. It's a shame they don't provide an equivalent of the TimeSpan.TotalHours property.